# NoSuchMethodError on startup in Java Jersey app

Tags: java, maven, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I've been getting a very strange error when trying to start a Jersey app on Tomcat. The same code works on other computers. I tried reinstalling tomcat, all my maven dependencies, even Eclipse and Java itself, no luck. It seems like a bad Jersey version is being loaded, I think?

Any pointers in the right direction will be appreciated.

Here's the effective pom: http://pastebin.com/NacsWTjz

And the actual pom: http://pastebin.com/H6sHe4ce

```
2015-02-13 13:43:40,870 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/middleware-server] - StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:304)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:285)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1031)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5188)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Looks like you have incompatible jars in your classpath

Comment: I hope you are not in a jar hell.

Comment: I've been in jar hell for the last 3 days.. didn't get any work done because of that.

Comment: You have a version mismatch.  Can you post your pom?

Comment: Here's the effective pom, thank you so much: http://pastebin.com/NacsWTjz

Comment: One thing I don't see in the effective pom is the `javax.ws.rs.-api-2.0.1.jar`. Can you post the actual pom (here), and not the effective pom (somewhere else)

Comment: Just an FYI, this error is often a conflict of us using the jax-rs 1 api, when we really need the jax-rs 2 api

Comment: The actual pom: http://pastebin.com/H6sHe4ce

Comment: That doesn't help. We don't have the parent

Comment: It's parent: http://pastebin.com/P3wsKy5V and that parent's parent has the jersey stuff: http://pastebin.com/hKicrwDg

Comment: Run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` to see If any of the dependencies depend on `jsr-311`. In which case, you will need to exclude it

Comment: Also look in your tomcat libs. Maybe it is in there. I'll test your pom when I get a chance

Comment: There's 4 occurences of modules that rely on `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:jar:2.0.0:compile` which depends on jsr-311. There are 28 occurences of modules that depend on jsr-305.

Comment: Try and exclude it (jsr-311). jsr-311 is JAX-RS 1. This is a conflict as Jersey 2 uses JAX-RS 2, but there are still some classes like `Application` that are the same. JAX-RS 1 will not have the method `getProperties`, as shown in the exception.

Comment: Do this, just add `jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.3.2`. And don't worry about anything else. See if the app runs. This will cause the 2.0 not to be included. Not sure if it will break anything else though

Comment: You may be able to just exclude the jsr jar. Add `<exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>`  to the swagger dependency

Comment: So I've come to the conclusion that all you need to do is add the above exclusion to the swagger dependency. The Jackson 2.0 provider is overriden by a 2.4.1 provider. So we don't need to add it ourselves. When it's overriden, it seems to leave behind the jsr-311 jar. So if we exclude it, no one can attempt to use it, which looks to be the current problem

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much, please post it as an answer so I can give you the reputation you more than deseve.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

**Note:** Please see above comments for further discussion and tips.

This error usual means that you have a both a JAX-RS 1 and JAX-RS 2 jar on the classpath. Jersey 2 uses JAX-RS 2 (`javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar`), but if you have the `jsr311-api.jar` also, which is JAX-RS 1, there is a `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` in each jar. But the `jsr311-api` `Application` doesn't have the method `getProperties()` (hence `NoSuchMethodError`).

I've come to the conclusion that all you need to do is add the above exclusion to the swagger dependency. The Jackson 2.0 provider (which depends on JAX-RS 1) seems to be overridden by a 2.4.1 provider (which uses the new version). So we don't need to add it ourselves. When it's overridden, it seems to leave behind the `jsr311-api.jar`. So if we exclude it, no one can attempt to use it, which looks to be the current problem

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.11</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: In my case the `jsr311-api.jar` came with `spring-cloud-starter-eureka`, so excluding it there (like @peeskillet showed) solved my problem.

Comment: The version I am using is a little different: jaxrs-ri-2.28.zip. I am able to create a war file with maven.

Answer (score 0):

We are using `jersey-json` 1.9 which has a dependency on `jersey-core` which also happen to have a `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` class.

So our fix is to exclude the **jersey-core** from `jersey-json`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is related about "com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.18.3" (or any 1.* version) because old versions of Jersey didn't have that "public Map getProperties()" method.

And one of your dependencies use Jersey version 1 (you can check that in running mvn dependency:tree and search all jersey-core version used)

Me I have resolved the problem deleting all com.sun.jersey dependancies (old api) and using the new one org.glassfish.jersey API

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core