# Jersey does not work with Spring-Boot

Tags: java, maven, jersey, spring-boot

I'm using Spring-Boot to build my application, and now some of my modules need Jersey as a dependency. Then I can never start my application. Here are the original pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>GROUPID</groupId>
<artifactId>ARTIFACTID</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <ts.common.version>338.0.0</ts.common.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>twilio-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <!-- Using jcl-over-slf4j -->
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.carbonfive</groupId>
        <artifactId>db-migration</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.carbonfive</groupId>
        <artifactId>db-support</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This pom file works fine, until I add this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>1.19</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then I can never start it with this Error:

```
15:10:55.359 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
```

As requested, here are the full stack error info:

```
15:10:55.359 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:331) ~[jersey-server-2.22.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:172) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:364) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.22.1.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.28.jar:8.0.28]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:616) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:396) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:871) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext$JettyEmbeddedServletHandler.deferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.java:46) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.deferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.java:36) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.handleDeferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:166) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.start(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:113) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:290) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540) ~[spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at com.bwts.customer.BootStrap.main(BootStrap.java:21) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:467) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:467)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:871)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext$JettyEmbeddedServletHandler.deferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.deferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedWebAppContext.java:36)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.handleDeferredInitialize(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.jetty.JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.start(JettyEmbeddedServletContainer.java:113)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:290)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
    at com.bwts.customer.BootStrap.main(BootStrap.java:21)
    ... 6 more
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: My guess is you need to use Jersey 2.x (org.glassfish.jersey packages) instead of Jersey 1.x (com.sun.jersey packages).

Comment: Boot supports both Jersey 1 and Jersey 2 (and has samples for both versions). @Elderry the full stack trace of the error would be helpful. A minimal example that reproduces the problem would be even better.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson, stack trace added. I want to use mailgun and it requires Jersey 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Jersey 1.x you don't use the `boot-starter-jersey` dependency. That is only for Jersey 2.x (which it pulls in & conflicts with Jersey 1.x; your current error).

For Jersey 1.x, there is no built in support (for auto creation of jersey servlet), as there is with Jersey 2.x with the boot starter. For 1.x, you simply create the Jersey servlet yourself as a servlet/filter registration bean.

For complete examples of both Jersey 1.x and 2.x, see [dsyer's repo examples](https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-jersey).

As an aside, why would you want to use Jersey 1.x anyway for a new project. If it's for multipart support, Jersey 2.x has multipart support. See [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart). If it's for the client (because you are familiar with it, as opposed to 2.x), it doesn't take long to learn the 2.x client. See [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html)

Comment: I use Jersey 1 just because [mailgun's doc](https://documentation.mailgun.com/libraries.html#java) told me to do so. And now I'm also trying find if it is able to work with Jersey 2.

Comment: I've never used it, but is the framework actually _tied_ to Jersey 1.x? Or is it just what the doc uses for its examples? If the latter, it shouldn't be too difficult to migrate the examples to 2.x

Answer (score 0):

The solution is already there on stackoverflow, please have a look on this:

[NoSuchMethodError on startup in Java Jersey app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509370/nosuchmethoderror-on-startup-in-java-jersey-app)