# Spring Jersey - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map

Tags: maven, spring-boot, jersey, maven-3, jersey-2.0

**UPDATE:** So I just want to point out that before I submitted this question, I attempted the solution that I've seen on similar stackoverflow questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509370/nosuchmethoderror-on-startup-in-java-jersey-app). It was still giving me runtime errors, so I decided to write this question. `mvn dependency:tree` is what I was looking for so thanks @dunni. With `mvn dependency:tree`, I was able to find the actual name of the jersey dependency that was breaking my application and updated the exclusion by changing it from:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

To:

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

This works now.

---

For the longest time, I've been working on this Spring Jersey REST application using 1 internal company repository. Now, I found out that a library I need to use only exists in a 2nd internal company repository. I updated my .m2 -> settings.xml configuration to add the reference to the new repo like so:

```
<settings>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>internal-repository1</id>
            <name>name</name>
            <url>http://repo1.company.com/repositories/</url>
            <mirrorOf>*, !repo2</mirrorOf>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>  
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>profile</id>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>repo1</id>
                    <name>repo1</name>
                    <url>http://repo1.company.com/repositories/</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>repo2</id>
                    <name>repo2</name>
                    <url>http://repo2.company.com/respositories/</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>                
    </profiles>

    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>profile</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

This works. I can see in the System.out that it attempts to download the repo2 exclusive dependency from repo1.company.com/repositories/. It fails, then it attempts to download it from repo2.company.com/repositories and it succeeds. The build continues, and eventually tomcat gets started up on localhost:8080 and everything is fine.

The problem is, whenever I try to access any of my Jersey REST endpoints I've set up, I get the runtime error mentioned in the question title:

```
ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[my.package.name] 
- Allocate exception for servlet my.package.name.JerseyConfig
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
```

I know for a fact that the issue lies somewhere in this new dependency I'm trying to use. When I comment out the dependency in my pom.xml, and re run the application, everything works fine. All REST endpoints are functional. Uncomment the dependency, re-run the application, and try to access my REST endpoints, and I get the above error.

How do I go about finding out why this dependency is breaking my Jersey application at runtime?

Comment: You have most probably a conflict in your dependency versions. Run `mvn dependency:tree` and post the output here.

Comment: Thanks @dunni. My question was **how** I go about finding out why it was giving me runtime errors, and `mvn dependency:tree` was exactly what I was looking for. Updated the `<exclusion></exclusion>` and now my application seems to be working fine. Also updated my question to show how I fixed the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By Seeing the error I can guess that there are some conflicts in jar files Please check if you have a both a JAX-RS 1 and JAX-RS 2 jar on the classpath. Jersey 2 uses JAX-RS 2 (javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar), but if you have the jsr311-api.jar also, which is JAX-RS 1, there is a javax.ws.rs.core.Application in each jar. But the jsr311-api Application doesn't have the method getProperties().

Comment: So I went back and checked (by running mvn dependency:tree per @dunni's suggestion). I didn't find `jsr311-api` exactly but what I did find was it  had a dependency with `com.sun.jersey:jersey-client`. So I added that as an exclusion to the dependency in my pom.xml and it seems to be working fine now.

Comment: Even though this didn't exactly answer my question, I'll still mark it as the correct answer since it did help me arrive to the answer.

Comment: FYI, jersey-core included a copy of jsr311-api in its .jar until v1.19. Anyone using or depending on a version before that may encounter this issue despite adding an exclusion to your pom.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same Exception, altough it was on different dependencies:

I got to change my sql driver version:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>6.2.2.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

Before, I was using version 6.1.0.jre8. [Here](https://github.com/OHDSI/WebAPI/issues/194#issuecomment-364422073) I got the clue.