# WAR fails to start on jetty9 in AWS but works on local installation

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, jetty-9

I have a maven project which produces a `.war` application. When I deploy this war in my local installation of jetty9 the app works. When I deploy to my machine in AWS it fails to start with the following error.

```
2017-07-05 17:53:43.336:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3dd3bcd{/my-app,file:/var/cache/jetty9/data/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-my-app.war-_my-app-any-5436545420435013189.dir/webapp/,STARTING}{/my-app.war}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:331)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
```

This is a Jersey 2 app which communicates with another api via an old client written in Jersey 1. I've already had conflicts between both versions of Jersey and solved them using maven exclusions as [indicated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509370/nosuchmethoderror-on-startup-in-java-jersey-app), and that solved the problem locally, but for some reason it now fails when I deploy.

I've failed to spot the difference between the two environments. I ran `java -jar /usr/share/jetty9/start.java --version` and the result is identical (I diffed it) in both machines:

```
Jetty Server Classpath:
-----------------------
Version Information on 38 entries in the classpath.
Note: order presented here is how they would appear on the classpath.
      changes to the --module=name command line options will be reflected here.
 0:         (none specified) | ${jetty.home}/eclipse-ecj-3.11.0.jar
 1:         9.2.18.v20160721 | ${jetty.home}/jetty9-apache-jsp.jar
 2:                    1.2.5 | ${jetty.home}/taglibs-standard-impl.jar
 3:                    1.2.5 | ${jetty.home}/taglibs-standard-spec.jar
 4:                   8.0.37 | ${jetty.home}/tomcat8-api-8.0.37.jar
 5:                   3.0.FR | ${jetty.home}/tomcat8-el-api-8.0.37.jar
 6:                   8.0.37 | ${jetty.home}/tomcat8-jasper-8.0.37.jar
 7:                   8.0.37 | ${jetty.home}/tomcat8-jasper-el-8.0.37.jar
 8:                   2.3.FR | ${jetty.home}/tomcat8-jsp-api-8.0.37.jar
 9:                   8.0.37 | ${jetty.home}/tomcat8-juli-8.0.37.jar
10:                   8.0.37 | ${jetty.home}/tomcat8-util-8.0.37.jar
11:                   8.0.37 | ${jetty.home}/tomcat8-util-scan-8.0.37.jar
12:                    (dir) | ${jetty.base}/resources
13:                   3.1.FR | ${jetty.home}/servlet-api-3.1.jar
14:         9.2.18.v20160721 | ${jetty.home}/jetty9-http.jar
15:         9.2.18.v20160721 | ${jetty.home}/jetty9-server.jar
16:         9.2.18.v20160721 | ${jetty.home}/jetty9-xml.jar
17:         9.2.18.v20160721 | ${jetty.home}/jetty9-util.jar
18:         9.2.18.v20160721 | ${jetty.home}/jetty9-io.jar
19:         9.2.18.v20160721 | ${jetty.home}/jetty9-jndi.jar
20:                    1.5.6 | ${jetty.home}/javax.mail.jar
21:         9.2.18.v20160721 | ${jetty.home}/jetty9-security.jar
22:         9.2.18.v20160721 | ${jetty.home}/jetty9-servlet.jar
23:         9.2.18.v20160721 | ${jetty.home}/jetty9-webapp.jar
24:         9.2.18.v20160721 | ${jetty.home}/jetty9-deploy.jar
25:         9.2.18.v20160721 | ${jetty.home}/jetty9-plus.jar
26:         9.2.18.v20160721 | ${jetty.home}/jetty9-annotations.jar
27:                   3.0.FR | ${jetty.home}/tomcat8-annotations-api-8.0.37.jar
28:                      5.1 | ${jetty.home}/asm-commons-5.1.jar
29:                      5.1 | ${jetty.home}/asm-5.1.jar
30:                   1.1.FR | ${jetty.home}/tomcat8-websocket-api-8.0.37.jar
31:         9.2.18.v20160721 | ${jetty.home}/jetty9-websocket-client-impl.jar
32:         9.2.18.v20160721 | ${jetty.home}/jetty9-websocket-server-impl.jar
33:         9.2.18.v20160721 | ${jetty.home}/jetty9-websocket-api.jar
34:         9.2.18.v20160721 | ${jetty.home}/jetty9-websocket-client.jar
35:         9.2.18.v20160721 | ${jetty.home}/jetty9-websocket-common.jar
36:         9.2.18.v20160721 | ${jetty.home}/jetty9-websocket-server.jar
37:         9.2.18.v20160721 | ${jetty.home}/jetty9-websocket-servlet.jar
```

My question is: what could be different in the AWS machine that could cause this error? Where else should I look to get more info to solve this problem?

Comment: looks like some sort of version mismatch

Comment: What's the version of the servlet container you are deploying the WAR to on AWS?

Comment: It's jetty 9.2.18-1

Comment: _"This is a Jersey 2 app which communicates with another api via an old client written in Jersey 1"_ - Why? You should be using the 2.x client. Fix this, and I'm sure you'll fix your problem.

Comment: @peeskillet The client using jersey 1 is legacy code I'm more or less stuck with. We have plans to rewrite the whole thing using jersey 2, but It's a lot of code.

Comment: Is it the same error (as the one you posted) when you deploy?

Comment: I only get the error when I deploy in AWS. The same app works fine in my local installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the exclusions were not correctly configured. I was excluding `com.sun.jersey:jersey-server` but `javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api` was being included as a transitive dependency of `com.sun.jersey:jersey-client`. I explicitly excluded `javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api` and it worked.

I still don't know why it was working in my local jetty installation. A teammate suggested it may have something to do with the order the jars where loaded on each machine, but I'm not sure how to check that.