# Can't find javax.ws.rs.core on server, not on client

Tags: java, tomcat, gradle, jersey, javax.ws.rs

I am building a REST API that works perfectly on my local development machine, however when I deploy the exact same war file to my test server I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
```

I have checked my dependencies and I could not find a collision in it's build script and I have the folling line in my build.gradle

```
compile group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'javax.ws.rs-api', version: '2.1-m09'
```

For reference I am running on tomcat8 and java8 on both machines

Does anyone know what could cause this behaviour?

From running gradle dependency

```
+--- com.wordnik:swagger-jaxrs_2.10:1.3.13
|    +--- org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.4
|    +--- com.wordnik:swagger-core_2.10:1.3.13
|    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.3 -> 1.7.22
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.10:2.4.1
|    |    |    +--- org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.4
|    |    |    +--- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.4
|    |    |    |    \--- org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.4
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.1 -> 2.8.5
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.1 -> 2.8.5
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.1.1 -> 2.8.5
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0 -> 2.8.5
|    |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.5
|    |    |    +--- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:2.6
|    |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1
|    |    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:15.0 -> 20.0
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.1 -> 2.8.5
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jsonSchema:2.4.1
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.4.0 -> 2.8.5
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.4.1 -> 2.8.5
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.4.1 -> 2.8.5 (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.4.1 -> 2.8.4
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:2.8.4
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.4 -> 2.8.5
|    |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.4 -> 2.8.5 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.4 -> 2.8.5
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.4 -> 2.8.5 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:2.8.4
|    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.4 -> 2.8.5
|    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.0 -> 2.8.5
|    |    |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.4 -> 2.8.5 (*)
|    |    +--- com.wordnik:swagger-annotations:1.3.13
|    |    +--- org.json4s:json4s-ext_2.10:3.2.11
|    |    |    +--- org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.0 -> 2.10.4
|    |    |    +--- joda-time:joda-time:2.3
|    |    |    \--- org.joda:joda-convert:1.6
|    |    +--- org.json4s:json4s-native_2.10:3.2.11
|    |    |    +--- org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.0 -> 2.10.4
|    |    |    \--- org.json4s:json4s-core_2.10:3.2.11
|    |    |         +--- org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.0 -> 2.10.4
|    |    |         +--- org.json4s:json4s-ast_2.10:3.2.11
|    |    |         |    \--- org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.0 -> 2.10.4
|    |    |         +--- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:2.6
|    |    |         \--- org.scala-lang:scalap:2.10.0
|    |    |              \--- org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:2.10.0
|    |    |                   +--- org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.0 -> 2.10.4
|    |    |                   \--- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:2.10.0 -> 2.10.4 (*)
|    |    \--- org.json4s:json4s-jackson_2.10:3.2.11
|    |         +--- org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.0 -> 2.10.4
|    |         +--- org.json4s:json4s-core_2.10:3.2.11 (*)
|    |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.1 -> 2.8.5 (*)
|    \--- org.reflections:reflections:0.9.9 -> 0.9.10
|         +--- com.google.guava:guava:18.0 -> 20.0
|         +--- org.javassist:javassist:3.18.2-GA -> 3.20.0-GA
|         \--- com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:2.0.1
+--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.1-m09
+--- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.0-b05
+--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
+--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.8.RELEASE
|    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.2.2.RELEASE
|    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:4.2.2.RELEASE
|    |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.2.2.RELEASE
|    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    +--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:4.2.2.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.5.RELEASE -> 4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.25.1
|    +--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1 -> 2.1-m09
|    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.25.1
|    |    +--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1 -> 2.1-m09
|    |    +--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
|    |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:2.25.1
|    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:2.5.0-b32
|    |    |    +--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:2.5.0-b32
|    |    |    |    \--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1
|    |    |    \--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.5.0-b32
|    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.5.0-b32
|    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:2.5.0-b32
|    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.5.0-b32
|    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:aopalliance-repackaged:2.5.0-b32
|    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:2.5.0-b32 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-utils:2.5.0-b32 (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.javassist:javassist:3.20.0-GA
|    |    \--- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:1.0.1
|    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:2.5.0-b32 (*)
|    +--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.5.0-b32
|    \--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:2.5.0-b32 (*)
+--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.25.1
|    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.25.1 (*)
|    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.25.1 (*)
|    +--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1 -> 2.1-m09
|    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:2.25.1
|    |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.25.1 (*)
|    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:2.5.0-b32 (*)
|    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.5.0-b32
|    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:2.5.0-b32 (*)
|    |    \--- org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:1.0.1
|    +--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
|    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-api:2.5.0-b32 (*)
|    +--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.5.0-b32
|    +--- org.glassfish.hk2:hk2-locator:2.5.0-b32 (*)
|    \--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
+--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.25.1 (*)
+--- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.25.1
|    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:2.25.1
|    |    +--- org.glassfish.hk2.external:javax.inject:2.5.0-b32
|    |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.25.1 (*)
|    |    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.25.1 (*)
|    |    \--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1 -> 2.1-m09
|    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.25.1 (*)
|    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.25.1 (*)
|    \--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1 -> 2.1-m09
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0
+--- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.25.1
|    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.25.1 (*)
|    +--- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-entity-filtering:2.25.1
|    |    \--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1 -> 2.1-m09
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-base:2.8.4 (*)
|    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider:2.8.4 (*)
|    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.4 -> 2.8.5
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.9.Final -> 5.2.10.Final
|    +--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final
|    +--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
|    +--- org.javassist:javassist:3.20.0-GA
|    +--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
|    +--- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:1.0.1.Final
|    +--- org.jboss:jandex:2.0.3.Final
|    +--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.3.0
|    +--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
|    \--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.0.1.Final
|         \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.3.0.Final
+--- mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.39
+--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.4
|    +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2
|    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3 -> 1.2
|    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
+--- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1
|    +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.0.4 -> 1.2
|    \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.2 -> 1.6
+--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.7
+--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.7
|    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.7
\--- se.mulander.cosmos:common:1.1
+--- io.swagger:swagger-jersey-jaxrs:1.5.13
|    +--- io.swagger:swagger-jaxrs:1.5.13
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.5 (*)
|    |    +--- io.swagger:swagger-core:1.5.13
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.2.1
|    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.5
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.5 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.8.5
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.5
|    |    |    |    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17
|    |    |    +--- io.swagger:swagger-models:1.5.13
|    |    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.5
|    |    |    |    +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.22
|    |    |    |    \--- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:1.5.13
|    |    |    +--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0
|    |    |    \--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
|    |    +--- org.reflections:reflections:0.9.10 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.guava:guava:20.0
|    +--- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:1.13
|    |    +--- org.jvnet:mimepull:1.6
|    |    \--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.13
|    \--- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.13
+--- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.0-b05
+--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.3.8.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.2.2.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.2.2.RELEASE (*)
+--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.25.1 (*)
+--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.25.1 (*)
+--- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.25.1 (*)
+--- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.25.1 (*)
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0
+--- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.25.1 (*)
+--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.10.Final (*)
+--- mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.39
+--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.4 (*)
+--- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1 (*)
+--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.7
\--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.7 (*)
```

build.gradle

```
group 'se.mulander.scraper'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url '../maven'
    }
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testCompile group: 'com.mscharhag.oleaster', name: 'oleaster-matcher', version: '0.1.2'
    testCompile group: 'com.mscharhag.oleaster', name: 'oleaster-runner', version: '0.1.2'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '1.6.6'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito', version: '1.6.6'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4-rule', version: '1.6.6'

    compile('com.wordnik:swagger-jaxrs_2.10:1.3.13') {
        exclude group: 'javax.ws.rs'
    }
    compile group: 'javax.ws.rs', name: 'javax.ws.rs-api', version: '2.1-m09'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '4.0.0-b05'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '4.3.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '4.3.8.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-web', version: '4.2.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-config', version: '4.2.2.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-client', version: '2.25.1'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-server', version: '2.25.1'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.core', name: 'jersey-common', version: '2.25.1'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers', name: 'jersey-container-servlet', version: '2.25.1'

    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.0'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jersey.media', name: 'jersey-media-json-jackson', version: '2.25.1'

    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.2.9.Final'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.39'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.3.4'
    compile group: 'commons-httpclient', name: 'commons-httpclient', version: '3.1'

    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-api', version: '2.7'
    compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.7'

    compile('se.mulander.cosmos:common:1.1'){
        exclude group: 'javax.ws.rs'
    }
}

war {
    destinationDir(file('build/'))
}
```

Comment: have you checkout this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509370/nosuchmethoderror-on-startup-in-java-jersey-app, seems you have both  JAX-RS 1 and JAX-RS 2 jar on the classpath

Comment: I don't think that I have them both. I had that problem earlier because I used swagger that included JAX-RS 1. But now I have the following in my build.gradle `compile('io.swagger:swagger-jersey-jaxrs:1.5.13') {
        exclude group: 'javax.ws.rs'
    }` So I shouldn't have both versions... unless the server is importing it from outside the war

Comment: can you print out the dependency list? `./gradlew dependencies`

Comment: hmm, you might be onto something with JAX-RS versions... however I have set my build.gradle to exclude javax.ws.rs from se.mulander.common, although it still shows up for some reason

Comment: hmm, I did not see `jsr311-api` in your list?

Comment: That is true... I am not that familiar with all the dependencies needed, however if I add that to my build file, it crashes with the same message but on my local dev machine

Comment: do you mind pastebin your `build.gradle` as well?

Comment: I attached it to the question

Comment: cool, let me check it out locally.

Comment: Have you also checked if there is any `jsr311-api` jar in the `${TOMCAT_HOME}/lib`?

Comment: there isn't any jsr311-api jar on either the local computer or on the server

Comment: Kind of running out of ideas now. :(

Comment: aww :(   well, either way I really appreciate the help so far! :)